# obstruction cocycle for nonsimple spaces using local coefficients

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, obstruction-theory

This question is [similar to here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31147/obstruction-theory-for-non-simple-spaces) but I was hoping for a concrete theorem statement surrounding the obstruction cocycle for non-simple spaces.

I'm hoping for a theorem like the following:

> Let $A \subset X$ such that $\pi_1(A)=\pi_1(X)$ and $f:A \to Y$ be a function. Letting $\pi_n(Y)$ be a $\mathbb Z[\pi_1(A)]$ module, where $\pi_1(A)$ acts via $f_*$ and the usual action of $\pi_1(Y)$. Suppose that $H^*(X,A,\pi_n(Y))=0$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Then there exists an extension of $f$ to all of $X$. More generally if $\pi_1(X)=\pi_1(A)/N$ and $N \subset \ker f_*$, then if  $H^*(X,A,\pi_n(A)/N)=0$, there is an extension.

The slightly awkward generalization is due to my desire to prove the universal property for Quillen's plus construction presented in [these notes, prop 1.1.2](http://www.numdam.org/article/ASENS_1976_4_9_3_309_0.pdf).

---

A naive guess on my part would be to apply the usual obstruction theorem to the universal cover of $Y$, and then if we use local coefficients, we can ensure that  $f:A \to \tilde{Y}$ is a lift of $f:A \to Y$, but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: Note that this is a crosspost from [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3548165/obstruction-theory-for-fx-to-y-with-y-not-simple). If there are any issues with this question, I am happy to edit or remove it.

Comment: Given maps $i\colon A\rightarrow X$ and $f\colon A\rightarrow Y$ of pointed connected complexes, once you fix a homomorphism $\phi\colon \pi_1 X\rightarrow \pi_1 Y$ extending $f_\ast$, obstructions to extending $f$ up to homotopy along $i$ to a map $g\colon X\rightarrow Y$ with $g_\ast = \phi$ live in the cohomology groups $H^{n+1}_{\pi_1 X}(X,A;\pi_n Y)$. This comes from the Postnikov tower of $Y$, but I don't know a good reference; see also https://mathoverflow.net/q/328022/ .

Comment: See Baues's obstruction theory book, also the algebraic homotopy book, I think you'll find it in both.

Comment: Dear Fernando, please feel free to leave that as an answer, it is theorem 4.2.9 in the obstruction theory book. Assuming no errors, it is stated as follows:                                  Let $p:E \to X$ be a fibration with path-connected fiber and let $X_n=X^n \cup L$ and $E^(n)=p^{-1} (X^{(n)})$. Then for $n>1$ and( $n=1$ if $\pi_1(F)$ is abelian), given a section $u:X^{(n)} \to B^{(n)}$ there is an obstruction cocycle $c(u) \in C^{(n+1)}(X,L,\pi_n(F))$ so that the section can be extended to the n+1 skeleton if and only if it vanishes....

Comment: Taking the trivial bundle $p:X \times Y \to X$ and any map $f:X \to Y$ we write a section as $(x,f(x)) \in X \times Y$ and the previous theorem applies.